# Has anyone moved the free windows 10 'Retail version' to another PC successfully?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I read on a questions and answers thread on Microsofts website that the free Windows 10 becomes the type it was upgraded from (e.g retail version).

Other threads  seem to conclude it still acts like an OEM even in the case of the retail version binding only to the hardware it was  first installed on.

Has anybody managed to  reinstall Windows 10 on a new computer upgraded from a retail windows,  or did it lock to the First hardware?

The [EULA](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm) states "`you may transfer the software to another device that belongs to you`" so it looks possible ...

Steps to try:

- Install windows 7/8.1 retail on machine A
- Upgrade to windows 10 for free.
- Uninstall windows completely from machine A
- Install the same windows 7/8 retail on machine B
- Upgrade to windows 10 again (here's hoping)

If someone has already done the first to steps feel free to try see if it works!

I personally don't want to try the first to steps just in case I can't transfer it after if anyone has done this or has some insight please let me know.

Comment: The eula appears to be clear on the issue, yes you can.

Comment: Thanks, do you have link to someone who has done it with steps to reproduce?

Comment: Your steps are correct.

Comment: Ok great!    Haven't seen anybody doing it on the Internet,  I guess the reports I saw saying it can't be done were using OEM editions.